# Cannot find module 'firebase-functions' / Cloud-Functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

While trying to use Cloud functions in a Firebase app of mine, I hit the issue hereafter.

The functions/src/index.ts file contains this line:

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
```

generating the error below:

```
Type error: Cannot find module 'firebase-functions' or its corresponding type declarations.
```

While the functions/package.jason file contains these lines:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^11.8.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^4.3.1"
  },
```

It seems to me I have used similar code in the past without any problem, but why am I having this issue here ?